# T-SQL calculate percentage of count group by date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that has the following structure and trying to write a T-SQL to calculate percentage of the counts. The percentage for each row should be the percent of the total for one of the grouping which in my case is the date.

```
CREATE TABLE ProductSales
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    AccountId int NOT NULL,
    SaleDate date NOT NULL,
    ProductType varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    ProductSubType varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Amount money NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_ProductSales 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON PRIMARY
) ON PRIMARY
GO

INSERT INTO ProductSales (AccountId, SaleDate, ProductType, ProductSubType, Amount) 
VALUES  (1, CAST(N'2023-11-01' AS Date), N'Books', N'Comics', 12.0000),
        (2, CAST(N'2023-11-01' AS Date), N'Books', N'Comics', 22.0000),
        (3, CAST(N'2023-11-01' AS Date), N'Clothing', N'Polos', 2.0000),
        (4, CAST(N'2023-11-01' AS Date), N'Books', N'Fonics', 18.0000),
        (5, CAST(N'2023-11-02' AS Date), N'Clothing', N'Jackets', 22.0000),
        (5, CAST(N'2023-11-02' AS Date), N'Clothing', N'Polos', 18.0000),
        (2, CAST(N'2023-11-02' AS Date), N'Clothing', N'Jeans', 19.0000),
        (1, CAST(N'2023-11-02' AS Date), N'Clothing', N'Jackets', 187.0000)
```

I would like the last column as a percentage of total rows for each day as below. The calculation of percentage was done manually and not using T-SQL.

```
SaleDate    ProductType ProductSubType  Total   Percentage
----------------------------------------------------------
11/1/2023   Books   Comics  2   50.00%
11/1/2023   Books   Fonics  1   25.00%
11/1/2023   Clothing    Polos   1   25.00%

11/2/2023   Books   Comics  2   33.33%
11/2/2023   Clothing    Jackets 2   33.33%
11/2/2023   Clothing    Jeans   1   16.67%
11/2/2023   Clothing    Polos   1   16.67%
```

Here is my query that I tried. But the percentage is the total of all the rows. I need that by date.

```
DECLARE @startdt date = '2023-11-01', 
        @enddt date = '2023-12-13'

SELECT
    CAST(SaleDate as date) SaleDate, ProductType, ProductSubType, 
    COUNT(1) Total,
    (100.0 * COUNT(1) / (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ProductSales 
                         WHERE SaleDate BETWEEN @startdt AND @enddt)) AS 'Percentage'
FROM
    ProductSales 
WHERE
    SaleDate BETWEEN @startdt AND @enddt
GROUP BY 
    CAST(SaleDate AS date), ProductType, ProductSubType
ORDER BY
    SaleDate, ProductType
```

Comment: As a side question, do you have a *good* reason for using the `NOLOCK` hint, other than intentionally trying to get unreliable results?

Comment: I don't need the nolock hint. removed

Comment: And another side question: why is `Id` "labelled" as the primary key - but doesn't have a `PRIMARY KEY` notation in your SQL script? Without this, it's **not really** the table's primary key ....

Comment: @marc_s Yes I removed it from the script but now I added again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to correlate the subquery table with the main one, by doing WHERE innerTable.date = outerTable.date.

```sql
SELECT
    SaleDate, ProductType, ProductSubType, 
    COUNT(*) Total,
    (100.0 * COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ProductSales ps2
                         WHERE ps2.SaleDate = ps.SaleDate
                       --  group by ps.SaleDate
                         )) AS 'Percentage'
FROM
    ProductSales ps
WHERE
    SaleDate BETWEEN @startdt AND @enddt
GROUP BY 
    SaleDate, ProductType, ProductSubType
ORDER BY
    SaleDate, ProductType
```

Watch out for group by columns there.

But you can also bin the above and just use the windowed aggregation to avoid the subquery altogether:

```sql
SELECT
    SaleDate, ProductType, ProductSubType, 
    COUNT(*) Total,
    100.0 * COUNT(*) / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER(PARTITION BY SaleDate) AS 'Percentage'
FROM
    ProductSales ps
WHERE
    SaleDate BETWEEN @startdt AND @enddt
GROUP BY 
    SaleDate, ProductType, ProductSubType
ORDER BY
    SaleDate, ProductType
```

`SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER(PARTITION BY SaleDate)` summarizes the counts and generates the total sum which you can use to get the percentage